# removing usb device in python

Tags: python, usb

```
os.system('powershell $driveEject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application; $driveEject.Namespace(17).ParseName("""F:""").InvokeVerb("""Eject""")')
```

Here I am trying to remove USB drive. Problem is that its not removing when USB format is NTFS.

When format is FAT32 code works fine (I am using windows 11)